# VS Code - built-in formatter does not ident with the correct number of spaces

Tags: html, visual-studio-code

I'm experiencing an issue in VS Code when using the auto formatter to fix indentation in HTML files. On hitting the shortcut **Shift + Alt + F**, the document is indented with 4 spaces instead of 2.

Before using auto format:
[HTML written with emmet, before using auto format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zrz2n.png)

After using auto format:
[The same HTML, after hitting Shift + Alt + F](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RJ2yE.png)

Here are my user settings:

```
"editor.tabSize": 2,
"editor.insertSpaces": false,
"editor.detectIndentation": false,
```

Do these user settings have any influence on the auto-formatter for HTML? All other file types appear to indent correctly according to these settings, or with their associated linters.

I have no workspace settings set for the editor, just the user settings and no extensions installed that might change the way this behaves. I have also tried installing the Beautify extension by HookyQR and then setting various config files, these don't seem to influence this formatting behaviour. I have also tried HTMLHint, again no luck.

I am a bit stuck, and bored of manually formatting the indentation of my HTML files!

Comment: In the lower right-hand corner of the status bar does it say "Spaces:4" or "Spaces:2"?  If it says 4, click it and choose one of the first two options and change to 2.

Comment: @Mark it says 2. I'm pretty sure `editor.tabSize` setting controls that, but unfortunately I still have this issue!

Comment: @Mark to clarify, the lower right-hand corner of the status bar actually says "Tab Size: 2", because I am indenting using tabs (hence the setting `"editor.insertSpaces": false,`